# Grails upgrade 2.4.4 to 3.2.8, javascript and css sources producing blank, spring-security-shiro/core

Tags: grails, spring-security, shiro

I am upgrading an application to grails version 3.2.8 and am using the grails spring-security-shiro plugin. My links to css files and javascript files are not working. I have copies of all static resources in `grails-app/assets`.

```
grails-app/assets/js
grails-app/assets/css
grails-app/assets/images
grails-app/assets/fonts
```

I believe the spring-security-shiro (which ships with core) could be affecting rendering. Viewing the page source and clicking on one of the resources produces a blank page. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: the proper folder names in asset folder are `javasctipts`, `images` and `stylesheets`

Comment: @mcroteau I am running into the same issue - did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the contents of your `web-app` folder to `grails-app/assets/stylesheets`, `grails-app/assets/javascript` etc., as this is a new default location for static resources managed by [asset-pipeline](http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I moved everything into the assets directory. I actually have copies in both `grails-app/assets` and `src/main/webapp`. Still producing the same error.

Comment: you should be using `<asset:stylesheet href="somecss.css"/>` tags

Comment: I am actually in need of including these files in a way that is a little tricky. I am including them in the resource/page gsp as a variable, like so 

`${raw(page_header)}
gsp content
${raw(page_footer)}`

Where the `page_header` would contain the links to style sheets and js files (`<link rel="stylesheet"/>` etc.) Does this make sense? I am unable to use the `<asset:>` tag.

Comment: I'm doing smth like that as well: a template file `_header.gsp` containing lots of `<asset:javascript/>` and `<asset:stylesheet/>` tags